# How to get back uploaded image in edit mode in my form using ASP.NET MVC 5?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have created a form and I am inserting some data and image in my database using the form submit... But when I am opening in edit mode, all inserted data is available in the input fields except the image? How do I fix this?

---

### View:

```
@model User_Management_System_V2._0.Models.Product
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Edit";
}
<h2>Edit</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm("Edit","Products",FormMethod.Post , new { enctype = "multipart/form-data"}))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<div class="form-horizontal">
    <h4>Product</h4>
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    @*<div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ProductID, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ProductID, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ProductID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>*@
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ProductName)
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Description, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Description, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Description, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PriceExpected, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.PriceExpected, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PriceExpected, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.OldTime, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.OldTime, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.OldTime, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Status, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Status, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Status, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Photo, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
           <input type="file" name="file"/>
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Photo, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>


  </div>
}
<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

---

### Controller:

```
public ActionResult Edit(string id)
{
    if (id == null)
    {
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }
    Product product = db.Products.Find(id);
    if (product == null)
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }
    return View(product);
}
```

---

### Create Action

```
 public ActionResult Create()
    {

        return View();
    }


    [HttpPost]

    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "ProductName,Description,PriceExpected,OldTime,Status,Photo")]Product product,HttpPostedFileBase file)
    {          
            if (file != null)
            {
                product.Photo = new byte[file.ContentLength];
                file.InputStream.Read(product.Photo, 0, file.ContentLength);



            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Please Select image");
            }

            db.Products.Add(product);
            db.SaveChanges();



        return RedirectToAction("Index");

    }
```

My main problem is that all the fields are opening in edit mode which means they are opening in edit mode with the preinserted data values in their fields but the image is not having the preinserted value.

Comment: Could you post Create action code, my friend?

Comment: yes ! i have edited the post..help

Comment: You can't. A file input dialog in a browser doesn't work like that. The user has to select a file. You can't pre-populate it with a selected file because a) you don't have access to the user's disk and b) even if you did, you don't know if the file exists any more, or whether they are even using the same device to access your website. However since this is an image, what you _could_ do in your "edit" screen is display the existing uploaded image, so the user can decide if they want to replace it or not

Comment: thanx ADyson. But can you tell me I can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

try the following solution in jquery and pure Javascript you will only need to retrieve byte array of the image you uploaded and it's extension then just give your image control the generated src I hope it helps

```
 var PhotoArr = []; //array of bytes from the server
var PhotoExt = "jpg";//example
if (PhotoArr) {
    var byteArray = new Uint8Array(oldResume.PhotoArr);
    var blob = new Blob([byteArray], { type: 'application/' + PhotoExt });
    var image = $('#yourImageId');
    var urlCreator = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
    var imageUrl = urlCreator.createObjectURL(blob);

    image.attr('src', imageUrl);

}
```